# Nanoletters submission problem - pdf figures

Tags: pdf, tiff

I'm trying to submit a paper to Nano Letters. However, the site states it only accepts figures in pdf or tiff format instead of my usual eps format. So I tried replacing the figures with their pdf counterpart, but it does not work. It simply states that the figure is missing. Can't give you much of an error list, as it is part of the online incorporated submission system.

How to incorporate figures in pdf format?

Any other physicist encountered this problem with the ACS site?

Comment: Can you point me to these instructions? (I write `achemso`, but have very little control over things at the ACS end, so it's always useful to know what's going on!)

Comment: See my comment in the answer below. There I explain both issues... the "\bibliography{}", I already encountered it when submitting for ACS Nano, but it took me some time to remember it. And yes, I add the command now, but still keep my manually written bibliography. It put's two times the word "references", but that thing is sorted out when they will convert it to their proper typesetting language I guess. So I don't really think its a problem of achemso which works just fine, it's more related to the online run on the ACS website.

Comment: And for the instructions on pdf and tiff files, here is the link... http://pubs.acs.org/paragonplus/submission/popups/choosing_filetypes.html. I'll provide the pdf or tiff files if needed when further down the submission process. Most important to me now was to generate the proofs so the refereeing game can start :)

Comment: @Joseph Wright. Just this comment to point you back to the previous comment. Didn't know @ is important to have another commenter have a warning. And so, maybe you haven't seen it.

Comment: Thanks for that: I've never noticed that instruction before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all. I finally managed my way out. Pdf files were allowed, but were not incorporated in the text. Then I found a workaround to still incorporate my simple .eps file (for those interested, you have to upload them as "Tex/LaTeX Suppl File" instead of a "Graphic for Manuscript"). And then, most tricky part, their system expects a "\bibliography{xxx}" command, while in my case, i used a in-file manually written bibliography. I kept it that way, just adding a bogus call to external bibliography. They get rid of this double bibliography during proof generation.

Answer (score 3):

```
...
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
...
```

and then run the document with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` and all eps images will be converted to pdf and saved in a file `<file>-pics.pdf` with one page per image.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. But I'm not allowed to upload the .eps files on the website. I can only upload the .tex file and the .pdf files... the typesetting happens online.

Comment: @Nigu, can you upload the final output only?

Comment: After your run with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` you can replace all eps figures with the generated pdf's. Where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, that's the whole point, when running it in texshop on my computer, it works fine, but when doing it on the online system, it fails... and I get no output. I'll try to add the online log-file I just found.

Comment: @Herbet. The TeX system at the ACS is very restricted and very old: no e-TeX, for example!

Comment: @Nigu: YOu shouldn't run it online, you should edit your document and replace the eps files with the created pdf files! Then you can upload your document (without the auto-pst-pdf line) which now uses only pdf images, which you also can be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks to all. I finally managed my way out. Pdf files were allowed, but were not incorporated in the text. Then I found a workaround to still incorporate my simple .eps file (for those interested, you have to upload them as "Tex/LaTeX Suppl File" instead of a "Graphic for Manuscript"). And then, most tricky part, their system expects a "\bibliography{xxx}" command, while in my case, i used a in-file manually written bibliography. Commenting everything out one by one finally helped me to track down that nasty bug...

Comment: @Nigu: Please make this an answer or edit it into your question.